# I can't open a port for use with Storj

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, port

I'm trying to open a port for create a Storj node ([Storj](https://storj.io/) is a decentralized storage cloud for who don't know), so I followed all instructions but I cannot open a port. My router is a Tenda N300, and according to the instructions I need to open a port 28967 so I did it that in the port forwarding section of the router manager:
[image]

I obtained the IP address from ipconfig in the cmd:

[image]

I don't know if I should use some of the other two Ethernet ip. I'm using wifi through a wifi tp-link extender from which I connect pc via Ethernet

So I know that my port is closed because of this [page](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) which shows me my public IP and if the port is open or closed.

[image]

What could be happening?
I don't know much about networks so I'm not sure what other information I should provide.

Comment: Does your router's status screen show you exactly the same public IP (WAN IP) as the website does? (If they're not the same, search this site for "CGNAT"...)

Comment: No, it's not showing the same ip